# Can't Upload Image to the same row in sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, where-clause, pyodbc, freetds

I'm new to linux.I'm trying to upload image to a table in sql server database but i got an error. My database table has 3 columns id_number is the first column and it is set to auto increment and it is also the primary key. other columns are list inside the code below. I need to upload the image to where id_number == 1 (very first row of the table). but the below code gives me an error.

```
#! /user/bin/env python
import pyodbc 
from PIL import Image

dsn = 'nicedcn'
user = myid
password = mypass
database = myDB

con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO Image_table(name, img) VALUES (?,?) WHERE img_id = 1""",
    (pic1, pyodbc.Binary(bindata)))

cnxn.commit()
```

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180) (SQLParamData)')

Please Help me guys.. thank you

Comment: First things first: how are the name and img columns defined in SQL Server on the Image_table table? varbinary(max) should be img, if it isn't. Let me know.